# A question on Isometry between the orthogonal subspaces of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I was reviewing my class-notes on Functional analysis and the professor had mentioned that given a closed proper subspace $U$ of an hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, $\exists  $ a closed subspace  $U^{\perp}$ such that 
$U\oplus U^{\perp}=\mathcal{H}$ is an isometry from $\{<z,w>\} \to z+w$ where $z \in U,w\in U^{\perp}$

I know the definition of an isometry(that it is a distance preserving map between two metric spaces) but why is this map an isometry? And why isnt $U\oplus U^{\perp}$ the same as $\mathcal{H}$

I would be grateful if someone could help me out here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two understandings of the notation $U \oplus V$.

The first interpretation means that if you write $U \oplus V$, then $U$ and $V$ are both subspaces of a common inner product space and orthogonal to each other (i.e. $\langle x,y\rangle =0$ for $x\in U,y\in V$ and $U \oplus V=\{x+y\mid x\in U, y \in V\}$. In this interpretation, you have $\mathcal{H}=U \oplus U^\bot$.

In the second interpretation, $U,V$ can be different spaces(i.e. they don't have to be subspaces of a common inner product space) and

$$
U \oplus V :=\{ (u,v)\mid u\in U, v\in V\},
$$

equipped with the usual vector space structure and with the scalar product
$$
\langle (u,v), (a,b)\rangle = \langle u,a\rangle +\langle v,b \rangle. 
$$
This is the interpretation used in your statement.

That your map is an isometry is a consequence of Pythagoras theorem, ie that $\Vert u+v\Vert^2= \Vert u\Vert^2 +\Vert v\Vert^2$ if $u,v$ are orthogonal.